# Error ( json.decoder.JSONDecodeError ) during program execution

Tags: python

I get an error while running the program

code :

```
from ippanel import Client
import json
from unittest import mock
api_key = "My api key"
sms = Client(api_key)
creadit = sms.get_credit()
```

error :

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How should I proceed to solve the problem and run the program correctly?

Comment: what you see when you `print(sms)`?

Comment: <ippanel.client.Client object at 0x000001C28EA57CA0>